# MATLAB's filter: how to setup the initial conditions

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, convolution

I have a very simple problem: generate y_1, ..., y_n such that

y_t = x_t + a * y_{t-1} + b * y_{t-2}

where a, b, x_1,...,x_n are given, as are y_0 and y_{-1}. I can do this with **MATLAB** in 2 ways (with a loop and with some manual adjustments before using **filter**). How do I do this using the built-in allowance for initial conditions of **filter**?

My code is as follows:

```
clc; clear; tic;

n        = 20;
x        = (1:1:n)';  %//' this is here so code looks good in SO.com
yzero    = -3;
yminus1  = -4;
a        = 1;
b        = 1;
yinitial = [yminus1;yzero];

% alternative 1
y = zeros(n,1);
for i = 1:n
    if i == 1
        y(1) = x(1) + a * yzero + b * yminus1;
    elseif i == 2
        y(2) = x(2) + a * y(1) + b * yzero;
    else
        y(i) = x(i) + a * y(i-1) + b * y(i-2);
    end
end

% alternative 2
z    = x;
z(1) = z(1) + a * yzero + b * yminus1;
z(2) = z(2)             + b * yzero;
s    = filter(1,[1,-a,-b],z);

% alternative 3
r    = filter(1,[1,-a,-b],x,yinitial);


toc;
```

I was hoping to get the same answers for `y`, `s`, and `r`. But only `y` and `s` are the same and `r` is very different. What am I doing wrong please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first element of the initial conditions are slightly off in the third alternative.

You use initial conditions:

```
yinitial =

    -4
    -3
```

But the correct ones are

```
yinitialFix =

    -7
    -3
```

Why? the 4th argument in call to `filter` in alternative 3 contains the initial conditions: in so that these initial steps will be performed:

```
x(1) = x(1) + yinitialFix(1)
x(2) = x(2) + yinitialFix(2)
```

Hence, you've actually (implicitly) computed the correct values to `yinitialFix` yourself in alternative 2, in your initial step:

- initial step shifts `z(1)` by `a * yzero + b * yminus1 = -7`,
- in the same way, `z(2)` is shifted by `b * yzero = -3`.

---

With the applied fix, alternative 3

```
%// ...
%// alternative 3;
yinitialFix = [-7; -3];
r    = filter(1,[1,-a,-b],x,yinitialFix);
```

yields the same result as the two previous ones.

Comment: Thanks! Where does [-7;-3] come from? Is there a systematic way to generate it from yinitial?

Comment: @yurnero Happy to help. I've now included an explanation of this in the answer.

Comment: Your comment makes me realize that there is a systematic way to get yinitialFix. I thought about it and found one way and looked up another. I put them in a wiki answer below. In any case, you have my + and tick.

Answer (score 0):

For alternative 3, using `yinitial` as I have done is incorrect. Here are 2 ways to fix it. First, I need to redefine `yinitial`:

```
yinitial = [yzero;yminus1];
```

Then, I get `xinitial` either from

```
xinitial = filter([b,a],1,yinitial);
xinitial = xinitial(end:-1:1);
```

**or** from

```
xinitial = filtic(1,[1,-a,-b],yinitial);
```

Then, I call

```
r        = filter(1,[1,-a,-b],x,xinitial);
```